# How to implement multiple roles in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to do a application with manages roles, and where one User can have multiple roles. I have created two models, one for the roles and other for the Users in models.py. My models.py looks like this:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    DOCTOR = 1
    NURSE = 2
    DIRECTOR = 3
    ENGENEER = 4
    ROLE_CHOICES = {
        (DOCTOR, 'doctor'),
        (NURSE, 'nurse'),
        (DIRECTOR, 'director'),
        (ENGENEER, 'engeneer'),
    }

    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices = ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_id_display()

class User(AbstractUser):
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
```

Now what I want to do is establish the roles from the User form. My forms.py looks like this:

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
    model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Insert username'
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Insert password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Again'


class RoleCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('id',)
```

And the views.py looks like this:

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = forms.UserCreationForm
    template_name = 'user_form.html'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:index')

class RoleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Role
    form_class = forms.RoleCreationForm
    template_name = 'role_form.html'
    redirect_field_name = 'index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:index')
```

How can I make to show all the roles in the User form and select multiple roles from there?

Comment: doesn't looks like `class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):` is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `UserCreationForm` is subclass of `forms.ModelForm` as well:

1) There are no `password1` or `password2` field in `User` model - only `password`. Hence, to make password confirmation you have to specify `confirm_password` field and override `clean` method to check that they are equal.

2) To show `roles` in form, you can just specify `'roles'` in list of fields. Since `roles` field exist in `User` model, django will find correct widget, display and validate it correctly.

3) You didn't wrote about it, but I guess you added [`AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<you_app_name>.User'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) to `settings.py`? That will change default `User` model to your app model.

4) Your `UserCreateView` will store password in plain text, which is *very* bad idea. Read more about [password management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers) on how to properly store passwords.

```py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'confirm_password', 'roles')
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
            'roles': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].label = 'Insert username'
        self.fields['password'].label = 'Insert password'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")

        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )
```

In reality you probably want to just create additional model with `OneToOneField` to `User` and `ManyToManyField` to `Role` instead of overriding django `User`, since replacing django `User` model can lead to problems.

Check out [django authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views). You can subclass [`AuthenticationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm) to add `Roles`.

Comment: with the `roles` attribute in the `fields` variable in the form it show me the roles selector, but is empty, how can I solve this?

Comment: You can populate them using django admin.

Comment: But I want to show the roles selector. When I try to create roles in the django admin, it shows me a selector with the roles that I defined in the Model, is there some way to do the same but in the `User` form?

Comment: You want to dynamically add different roles directly in form?

Comment: I want to select multiple roles from the user form

Comment: But you can select multiple roles(using shift). It's just default widget has this interaction. You can change it for example to checkbox widget. I can show example in about 6 hours.

Comment: @PaulMiranda I've updated form to use `CheckboxSelectMultiple` for `roles` field. It's simple and intuitive enough to select multiple roles from user form.